# Jquery mobile button icon won't change (through code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a button in jquery mobile which toggles between a list and grid view. However I am stuck getting the button icon to change when I press/click it. This is my code:

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:changeLayout()" class="ui-btn-right" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="b" data-inline="true"></a>
```

Javascript

```
function changeLayout() {
if ($('#changeLayout').data('icon') == 'grid'){
    $('#changeLayout').data('icon', 'bars');
    $('#changeLayout .ui-icon').addClass('ui-icon-bars').removeClass('ui-icon-grid');
}
else {
    $('#changeLayout').data('icon', 'grid');
    $('#changeLayout .ui-icon').addClass('ui-icon-grid').removeClass('ui-icon-bars');
}
```

However the button icon doesn't change. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery `.data('x')` does not read/write to an element's `data-x` attribute - it reads/writes to a background set of data handled solely by jQuery. You instead need to use the `.attr()` method.

Try the following instead:

```
function changeLayout() {
if ($('#changeLayout').attr('data-icon') == 'grid'){
    $('#changeLayout').attr('data-icon', 'bars');
    $('#changeLayout .ui-icon').addClass('ui-icon-bars').removeClass('ui-icon-grid');
}
else {
    $('#changeLayout').attr('data-icon', 'grid');
    $('#changeLayout .ui-icon').addClass('ui-icon-grid').removeClass('ui-icon-bars');
}
```

Note that while the jQuery docs say you can use `.data('x')` to access `data-x`, I've never seen it actually work. Changing to `.attr('x')` always fixes the issue as long as there are no other problems in the code.

Comment: You may need to call either `$("#changeLayout").button("refresh")` or `$("#changeLayout").buttonMarkup("refresh")` after the change to make the button's appearance update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really stupid. I forgot to assign the id of changelayout to my button in the HTML. My bad, thanks though!